# Converting Right String to Float

Tags: haskell

I'm struggling with converting a Right String. I have a method called getEval which evaluates a math expression (a String basically), and I get it back as follows:

```
*Main> getEval "3+6"
Right "9"
```

the type of getEval is

```
*Main> :t getEval "3+6"
getEval "3+6"
:: (Functor m, Control.Monad.CatchIO.MonadCatchIO m) =>
   m (Either InterpreterError String)
```

getEval looks like this:

```
getEval str = runInterpreter $ setImports ["Prelude"] >> eval str
```

If it matters, getEval uses the eval in Haskell's hint library (Language.Haskell.Interpreter) to do the actual parsing and calculation.
How can I get this into a float?

Comment: `liftM read (getEval "3+6")`. You may need to give ghci type signatures.

Comment: It's (semantically) the same as `fmap`, if you know that one (I overlooked the `Functor` constraint at first, so went for the `Monad` version). Its type is `liftM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`.

Comment: Hmm, I get the following error on this:
<interactive>:201:13:
    Couldn't match expected type `String'
                with actual type `Either InterpreterError String'
    Expected type: m0 String
      Actual type: m0 (Either InterpreterError String)
    In the return type of a call of `getEval'
    In the second argument of `liftM', namely `(getEval "3+6")'

I edited the original question and included a version of getEval that produces the same error.. hopefully that makes this more clear.

Comment: Ah, d'oh, miscounted Monads/Functors, `fmap (fmap read)` (or `liftM (liftM read)`). But that gives you an `m (Either InterpreterError Float)`, so `fmap (either (error . show) read)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getEval str = do
        Right res <-  Interpreter.runInterpreter (Interpreter.setImports
                ["Prelude"] >> Interpreter.interpret str (Interpreter.as ::
                Float))
        return res
```

Answer (score -2):

```
case getEval "3+6" of
  Right value  = read value :: Float
  Left  errstr = error ("Interpreter error" ++ errstr)
```

ought to do what you're expecting. You'd probably want to look at `readsPrec` as well, if you're concerned about `Read` parsing errors.

Comment: Wrong syntax. `case` uses `->`, not `=`.

Comment: And has the problem that `getEval` returns an `m (Either ...)`.